# Custom ordering multiple strings within a single list in python

Tags: python, string, list

```
data = ['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC',
        'ID:b22 EM:b@d.c ST:VIC GE:F FN:Miniyi LN:Li MN:0430101210 MN:0432101215',
        'ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']
```

I want the following data to be arranged in the order of

```
key_order = 'ID', 'GE', 'FN', 'LN', 'MN', 'EM', 'ST'
```

I can do it when there is one string using this code:

```
data = ['ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']
data = data[0].split()
keyorder = ['ID', 'GE','FN','LN','MN','EM', 'ST']
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x: key_order.index(x.split(':')[0]))) 

['ID:153', 'GE:m', 'FN:John', 'LN:Liu', 'MN:040181010', 'EM:d@b.c', 'ST:NSW']
```

Also having trouble for the final result to be displayed as:

```
ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC
ID:b22 EM:b@d.c ST:VIC GE:F FN:Miniyi LN:Li MN:0430101210 MN:0432101215
ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c
```

Thanks heaps

Comment: The second line of your desired output looks incorrect.

Comment: @James The third, too.

Comment: yes sorry i realised that and didnt know how to edit and by that time you posted the answer already haha. too quick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close to the right answer:

```
def sort_by_key(x):
    return key_order.index(x.split(':')[0])
for d in data:
    print(" ".join(sorted(d.split(), key=sort_by_key)))
#ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC
#ID:b22 GE:F FN:Miniyi LN:Li MN:0430101210 MN:0432101215 EM:b@d.c ST:VIC
#ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 EM:d@b.c ST:NSW
```

Comment: omg i struggled with this for weeks and you did it in a few seconds! amazing!! Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it